# Toggling states in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have used states in my application.The thing is I have made the first item in my list to be selected. so I gave like this,

```
if(itemIndex == 0)
  this.currentState="selected";
```

this works fine.The problem is when other item is selected the first item does not change its state,it remains in the selected state until its clicked.
My code looks like this,

```
<s:BorderContainer id="outerCont" width="275" height="100" borderVisible="false"
                       backgroundColor.normal="#3D3C3C" backgroundAlpha.selected="0.1"
                       backgroundColor.selected="{data.color}">
```

My states are like this,

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="hovered" />
    <s:State id="selState" name="selected" />
</s:states>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code for changing states, you never change back to a default state.  So, when itemIndex is 0; you set to the selected state; but have no shown code to move away from the selected state.  Try something like this:

```
if(itemIndex == 0)
  this.currentState="selected";
else 
  this.currentState="someOtherState";
```

To change state when something is selected in a Flex List you can use the change event:

```
<s:List change="onChange()" />

<fx:Script><[[
  public function onChange():void{
   if(itemIndex == 0)
     this.currentState="selected";
   else 
     this.currentState="someOtherState";
   }
]]></fx:Script>
```

Does that help?  If not; you'll have to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, my expectation is by default when the app loads the first item should be selected.So in creationComp i have given the code  if(itemIndex == 0)
  this.currentState="selected"; .After that when any other item is clicked the first item which is selected by default does not gets unselected unless and until it is clicked again.so i have two items gets selected.Hope its clear now..

Comment: @Naveen Your comment is actually more confusing.  For many Flex List based Components; the default state is "nothing selected".  Since you never told us what component you are using and how items are being selected; I'm at a loss at what to tell you next. I suggest you add more code, possibly a runnable sample to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hey sorry I ll try to explain you clearly  this time. I'm trying something similar to the on posted in the follwing link. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/27/creating-a-fancy-spark-list-control-item-renderer-in-flex-4/.I followed the same code,the only addition i have made is in my creation complete method i have made my first item to be selected, like this  'protected function itemrenderer1_initializeHandler():void
   {
    if(this.itemIndex==0)
    {
     //this.selected=true;
        this.currentState="selected";
     validateNow();
    }
   }'

Comment: If I select some other item the first item's state is not changing to normal.So I got stuck here.

Comment: @Naveen It appears that Stack Overflow ate your link.  If you're trying to select the first item in a list; on the list you should do: myList.selectedIndex = 0; .  Permanently setting the first item Renderer's state to selected will not automatically change it back to something else when it is deselected.